# Registry Access from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, registry

I keep getting: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TestSite\Foo' is denied.

I have granted full permission to "Everyone" for this key. I'm using windows server 2008 r2.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the obvious, some principals are not part of Everyone:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278259

This might be your problem.